# Xna and server as console application - GameTime

Tags: c#, xna

Hi I am coding small game in xna, i finished client side nad now doing server. But server is a console while client xna application. I use the same model based on managers.

Now i need to make update of my managers in server side while my manager take as parameter gateTime,what can i do to pass gateTime in loop in server console application? manually calculate how much time pased since last loop turn? In console i don't even see GameTime to crate it and pass to model manager.

Comment: You can get more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a structure similar to what XNA creates, ignoring the `Draw()`ing part. The code is already there, just remove what you will not use and the `gameTime` will be there.

You can and should reuse all the code you can, if it doesn't brick your program or make it harder to work on it and mantain.

Comment: but i need this information like gameTime server side to sync all my clients

Comment: And its exactly what I'm pointing you. You can create your server with the base of a XNA project and the boilerplate code will have gameTime.

Comment: ok but i dont need 99% of xna on server side.

Comment: This is why I said to get only what you need. If not, you will have to build your own gameTime management.